# Angularfire2 - How to filter multiple FirebaseListObservable in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2, angularfire2

I'm using ionic 2 to develop chat application that provide some functions like block, delete massage, etc.. My problem in block function and I'm searching for a way to filter firebase list by using an other list

here my code to get the lists

```
public chatList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
public blockList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
...
...
this.chatList = this.afd.list('/chats/',{
   query:{
      limitToLast:50
   }
});
this.blockList = this.afd.list('/blocks/');
```

and this is a picture for tree of these lists
[tree of chats and blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOXqs.png)

I tried to use this way to filter my lists but it doesn't work

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let chat of chatList | async" [hidden]="filter(chat)">
```

TS

```
filter(chat):boolean{
  this.blockList.subscribe(data => {
  data.forEach(block => {
    if(block.blockFrom==this.userService.email && block.blockTo==chat.email){
      return true;
     }
   })
 })
 return false;
}
```

Is there any other way to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we're working with Observables, they are more than equipped to handle this use case.

Combine the two Observable streams, and map out the filtered data.
As such:

```
public chatList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
public blockList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
public filteredList: Observable<any[]>;
...
...
this.chatList = this.afd.list('/chats/',{
   query:{
      limitToLast:50
   }
});
this.blockList = this.afd.list('/blocks/');
this.filteredList = Observable.combineLatest(this.chatList, this.blockList)
  .map(([chats, blocked]) => {
    let filtered: any[];
    ... // Do filtering here

    return filtered;
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let chat of filteredList | async">
```

The optimal solution, however, would probably be to rethink your Firebase data structure (if possible), so the filtering can happen there instead of in the client. But the above should do it.

Comment: Thank u v.much @DarkNeuron. I checked ur code but I don't know why there is no data shown as before. Can u learn me how can I use this combined list without filters to understand the idea?  because I didn't use this way before so I don't know how can I display the data of filteredList

Comment: Well combineLatest takes the latest emission from each Observable; so if chatList gets updated, blockList will contain the same values. So basically inside the map function, you would do your normal filtering on the chats array, like you were already doing. Remember: chats is an array of chats, and blocked is an array of blocked.